# How to Insert an Array of Values to a Symbolic Function in Python

Tags: python, substitution, symbolic-math

I want to study symbolic functions in python. I want to create `y(x) = x^2 + 2x + 3` and plot it in the range `[1, 255]`. I want to use the `subs()` function to calculate the values by using the `for` loop. However, when I run that I get this error:

```
IndexError('list index out of range')
```

Can you help me please?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from sympy import *

a = [1,2,3]

x = Symbol('x')
fx = a[0]*x**2 + a[1]*x + a[2]

t = list(range(1,256))
y = np.zeros(256)

for i in t:
    y[i] = fx.subs({x:t[i]})

plot.plot(t,y)
plot.show()
```

Comment: Can you show us the whole tracelog and not just one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace with the following lines:

```
y = np.zeros(len(t))

for i in range(len(t)):
    y[i] = fx.subs({x:t[i]})
```

The problem was that the length of `t` was only `255` but the len of `y` was `256` in your code because you define `y = np.zeros(256)`, hence the `Index Error` because there is no `t[256]`.  I am using `y = np.zeros(len(t))` because you have as many `y` points as `t` (or `x`) points. By the way, you are most likely to get an error in your plot command the way it is right now because you have called `import matplotlib.pyplot as plot`. I would simply call it `plt` instead of `plot`

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError("'function' object has no attribute 'plot'")

Comment: Glad to be of assistance!